# Find price of stock to buy in order to maximize the profit?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I have faced one question recently.

In that we are given an input consisting all the time span with the stock price in that particular time span.

Our objective is to find and display the best stock price among all the time spans in order to maximize the profit.

Example :

Input:

09:00 a.m. - 10:00 am.m.   - Rs. 80

09:00 a.m. - 11:00 am.m.   - Rs. 50

10:00 a.m. - 11:00 am.m.   - Rs. 30

10:00 a.m. - 13:00 am.m.   - Rs. 90

11:00 a.m. - 14:00 am.m.   - Rs. 70

12:00 noon - 14:00 am.m.   - Rs. 40

14:00 a.m. - 15:00 am.m.   - Rs. 45

Output:

09:00 a.m. - 10:00 am.m.   - Rs. 50

10:00 a.m. - 11:00 am.m.   - Rs. 30

11:00 a.m. - 12:00 am.m.   - Rs. 70

12:00 a.m. - 14:00 am.m.   - Rs. 40

14:00 a.m. - 15:00 am.m.   - Rs. 45

I tried solving this is several ways like using DS. Considering only start time and other ways too.

Can you please help by giving me some suggestions ?

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the input into an object.

Input.java

```
public class Input {
    // translate time period to list, like "9", "10", "11"
    private ArrayList<String> times = new ArrayList<>(); 
    private Double value;

    public ArrayList<String> getTimes() {

        return times;
    }

    public void setTimes(ArrayList<String> times) {

        this.times = times;
    }

    public Double getValue() {

        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Double value) {

        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Use StockPrice to store values. And put the smallest value to each element.
StockPrice.java

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class StockPrice extends HashMap<String, Double> {

    Map<String, Double> values = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public Double put(String key, Double value) {
        Double var = values.get(key);
        if ( var == null || var > value ) {
            values.put(key, value);
            return value;
        }

        return var;
    }

    public void put(Input input) {
        for (String time : input.getTimes()) {
            put(time, input.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

The keys is like "9","10","11"..., the value is smallest stock price.